# How do I also save the callee-saved registers when calling a function pointer?

Tags: c, low-level

Normally, when function A calls function B, function A will save all caller-saved registers (that are live) before doing the call to function B. In my (somewhat esoteric) usecase function B will be invoked through a function pointer and can also possibly overwrite callee-saved registers without saving them. That means A also has to save the callee-saved registers before invoking B. I looked up the possibility of using a custom calling convention for the function pointer but that solution didn't pan out. I'm using gcc (or clang) and compiling for ARM, but if at all possible I'd like to avoid inline assembly or compiler-specific constructs to make the code as general as possible. Anyone have a good suggestion? :-)

Comment: If you're programing in C you should not mess with the registers. the whole Idea behind C is to hide away hardware implementation..

Comment: If you save all registers the code would be as general possible?

Comment: So your function does not conform to the platform ABI, and you want to call it without using assembly language? Something tells me this ain't gonna work.

Comment: @n.m. It conforms to the ABI, _except_ for the callee actually saving callee-saved registers.

Comment: ... though there is one possible route, setjmp, call the function, longjmp. It is not guaranteed to work but there are good chances you will be able to get away with it.

Comment: "Conforms except ...." is a longer, more confusing way to spell "doesn't conform".

Comment: "... Anyone have a good suggestion? :-)" Sure: Do not even think about registers, stack, etc. Why would you want to do this actually?

Comment: @n.m. That's an interesting approach. I'll look into that, thanks.

Comment: @BertAbrath What possible use could there be for you in messing with the registers? And if there is, why are you programming in c and not assembler?

Comment: @Olaf It involves an application running in two different contexts that invoke each other through signals.

Comment: @BertAbrath: Still no reason to fiddle yourself. Use threads!

Comment: There is no standard way of calling a function that doesn't conform to the ABI. Whatever you do will necessarily be compiler-dependent.

Comment: @n.m. Unbelievably enough using setjmp actually works. I will use it as temporary measure. Ultimately it is probably best to ensure the functions called through the function pointer conform to the ABI, but that will take more work.

Comment: Saving registers ist not enough to be async-safe (i.e. safe in presence of signals), probably you are lucky with setjmp. I understand the question now as an xy problem. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378

Comment: It kind of sounds like you are trying to write a fibers (AKA co-routines) library (where you have multiple "thread" contexts but you explicitly select when to change context).  Perhaps look at using one of the existing ones?